# If my firewall is switched off,what else could be blocking access to mysql?

Tags: networking, centos, firewall, mysql, remote-access

I want to have remote access to my mysql server but when i telnet my server from my computer i get this

```
C:\Users\USER>telnet 197.000.0.00 3306
Connecting To 197.000.0.00...Could not open connection to the host, on port 3306
: Connect failed
```

and this

```
C:\Users\USER>telnet 197.000.0.00
Connecting To 197.000.0.00...Could not open connection to the host, on port 23:
Connect failed
```

I also tried nmap

```
C:\Users\USER>nmap -PN -p 3306 197.000.0.00

Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-09-16 09:59 
Nmap scan report for 197.000.0.00
Host is up.
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
3306/tcp filtered mysql

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 39.66 seconds
```

I also did witch off all my firewalls

```
[root@globan globan]# service ip6tables status
ip6tables: Firewall is not running.
[root@globan globan]# service iptables save
iptables: Saving firewall rules to /etc/sysconfig/iptables:[  OK  ]
[root@globan globan]# service iptables stop
iptables: Setting chains to policy ACCEPT: filter          [  OK  ]
iptables: Flushing firewall rules:                         [  OK  ]
iptables: Unloading modules:                               [  OK  ]
[root@globan globan]# chkconfig iptables off
[root@globan globan]# service iptables status
iptables: Firewall is not running.
[root@globan globan]#
```

I also did netstat

```
[root@globan globan]# netstat -tapnl | grep 3306
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306                0.0.0.0:*                   LIST
EN      21517/mysqld
[root@globan globan]#
```

My os is centos.

What could be the reason why i can't telnet my server successfully even though my firewalls are off?.

Comment: `197.000.0.00` is not a valid IPv4 IP address

Comment: I used zeros to mask the real ip address.

Comment: Is that an external IP or internal?

Comment: its an external ip.

Comment: So how is the infrastructure setup? For example your computer in these tests above is it on the same LAN as the Server, you mentioned turning the firewall off but for an external IP you will need port forwarding to the Centos Server, etc?

Comment: Nope,my computer is in my office,the servers are in the data center of the BT data centers.